# Adding HTML elements and class attributes to Contentful CMS Markdown content?

Tags: markdown, contentful

We need to have some basic `<div>` and `<div class="someclass"> This is our text </div>` type info in our content delivered via Contentful API. Basically something to denote sections and classes.

Is it possible to add this using Contentful Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to use a markdown parser which supports that. If you take a look at Kramdown for Ruby (for instance), you'll see it has a way of defining classes by using specific syntax. You just need to check whether the parser you're using has this kind of feature, and the required syntax